# Vim Auto Indent with newline

Tags: vim, indentation

How do I get vim to place the cursor within the braces starting on a new line, ie with | denoting the cursor position :

```
class {
  |
}
```

right now with my settings it only does this

```
class {
|}
```

I got this in my .vimrc file
set autoindent shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 noexpandtab

Basically I just want how a normal IDE would indent it.

update:

I found how to do this with `inoremap { {<CR>}<Esc>O`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Put this in your .vimrc :

```
imap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<Tab>
```

Assuming `autoindent` and `smartindent` are set correctly, typing `Ctrl + Return` between braces will put your cursor where you want it to be.

Comment: is there anyway to map it to just enter tho?  Im kind of used to pressing just enter key as I been using eclipse all this while.

Comment: or is there anyway to integrate this within a indent file for a particular language?

Comment: I think that mapping such a functionality to the regular Return would mean making it a real function and do at least two RegExp tests each time you hit the key. It seems to be a bit overkill. That, and I'm afraid I'm not advanced enough for that. +1 for the indent file, though.

Comment: Here's a slight variation that is more compatible with plugins that remap <Tab> `imap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<C-t>`

Comment: Thanks, actually I found another one yesterday: `imap <C-Return> <CR><CR><C-o>k<S-s>` with `<S-s>` starting insertion at the right indentation level. Also I think that using `inoremap` should protect from side effects.

Comment: First, not all terminals are capable to send <C-Return> correctly. You might need to configure something: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter/42461580#42461580 Second, another alternative can use O, which will minimize cursor movements: `imap <C-CR> <CR><C-o><S-o>`

Answer (score 28):

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I found no `vimrc` file in home directory. Global `vimrc` file was in `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

There was almost nothing in this file. So for me it worked to add this 3 lines to the end of `/etc/vim/vimrc`

```
set autoindent
set cindent
inoremap { {<CR>}<up><end><CR>
```

When you will type `{` next time it will be changed by combination `{`, Enter, `}`, up, end, Enter. `cindent` and `autoindent` will add required amount of Tab's.

P.S. I'm not good in tuning up vim so some explanations may be not so accurate. It's how I think it works.

Comment: I added a "<Tab>" at the end of the last line to make it indent the middle line one step. I.e. inoremap { {<CR>}<up><end><CR><Tab>

Answer (score 24):

I found that [delimitMate](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/tree/master/doc) does exactly what you describe and more (that is, automatically inserting the ending `}`). Note you have to tell delimitMate to expand carriage returns by adding `let delimitMate_expand_cr=1` to your config.

From my observation, this is exactly the behaviour found in TextMate and SublimeText.

Comment: FYI for users of delimitMate + neocomplcache:  If you use the default neocomplcache .vimrc setup, you will need to adjust the <CR> mapping to accommodate both plugins. More info [here](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/issues/111).  My .vimrc now has `imap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() : '<Plug>delimitMateCR'` and both plugins work like I want them to

Comment: For `delimitMate` `expand_cr_1` hasn't been working recently. Instead, you can use `imap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<c-y>" : "<Plug>delimitMateCR"`.

Answer (score 12):

`autoindent` refers to it carrying over the *current* indentation level onto subsequent lines. To get it to indent according to syntax, you need to specify a flag like `smartindent` or `cindent` as well.

Comment: the indentation is not a prob, i just want a newline inserted automatically when i hit enter with the correct indentation

Comment: I'm confused. Are you outside of insertion mode? If you press `i` then `Return`, do you get the behavior you want?

Comment: Yes i'm in insert mode, what i want is when I press enter after { i want vim to put me on a new line within the closing }, basically the first block in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this in my `.vimrc`

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> InsertMapForEnter()
function! InsertMapForEnter()
    if pumvisible()
        return "\<C-y>"
    elseif strcharpart(getline('.'),getpos('.')[2]-1,1) == '}'
        return "\<CR>\<Esc>O"
    elseif strcharpart(getline('.'),getpos('.')[2]-1,2) == '</'
        return "\<CR>\<Esc>O"
    else
        return "\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction
```

The code above first check if you are using `Enter` to do confirm a  code completion, if not it will indent the `{|}` when you type `Enter`. Also, it provides html tags auto indent.

For your problem:

```
class {|}
```

press `Enter` and you will get

```
class {
    |
}
```

```html
<html>|<html>
```

press `Enter` and you will get

```html
<html>
    |
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

At bottom of the file, I'm using:

```
# vim: ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sr noet st ai si
```

For example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos-7
RUN ...
CMD ...

# vim: ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sr noet st ai si
```

If you want keep the indentation only, use `# vim: st ai si`