# Create New Line While in Insert Mode

Tags: vim

I would like to use something like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create a new line in *Vim*.

So if `|` is the cursor, here is what I would like to do:

```
<%= some.code("in here") | %>
```

Now, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or something similar)
and get this as output:

```
<%= some.code("in here") %>
and my new line here |
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you also want it to indent to the position where you have your cursor `|` or just open a new line and the current autoindent level?

Comment: try `imap <leader>n <ESC>o`

Comment: Hey @MichaelBerkowski, just auto indent is fine.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Escape to Normal Mode

There are probably a number of ways to do what you want, but one option is to use CTRL-O to escape to normal mode to insert the line. For example <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> will open a new line below the current line and place your cursor there in insert mode.

If you want to map this rather than use it as a one-off, you can use an imap to set your mnemonic of choice. For example:

```
:imap \nn <C-O>o
```

will create an insert-mode mapping for <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> that will do the same thing.

Comment: Any way to map it to shift + enter?

Comment: @DavidBecerra Not as far as I know. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16359878/1301972 for answers to that question.

Answer (score 28):

`<ESC> o` - To open a line below

`<ESc> Shift + o` - To open a line above.

Answer (score 12):

I use `imap <C-o> <esc>o` to bind new line on Ctrl+O

Comment: I this case you overwrite the default <C-o> in insert mode which enters in normal mode for one command and switches back.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

As @alex-shwarc [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139047/create-new-line-while-in-insert-mode#comment72292797_18170018), `<C-o> o` (CTRL-o) gets you the behavior you want natively (and conversely `<C-o> O` to create a new line above and insert into it). `<C-o>` is really useful, see `:help i_CTRL-O`.