# alt-key binds in Vim: <A-D> won't work but <A-S-D> does

Tags: linux, vim, terminal

I am binding yankstack to these keys:

(note the `^[` here are the raw  char typed in with ctrl+v)

```
set <A-D>=^[d                                      
set <A-S-D>=^[D                                    
nmap <A-D> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_older_paste  
nmap <A-S-D> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_newer_paste
```

The `<A-S-D>` is properly interpreted, but the `<A-D>` is not.

Curiously, if I type `:set <A-D>`, I get back

```
     <Ä>        ^[D
```

So somehow it seems vim is thinking alt+d is equivalent to something that is not being sent by my terminal when I type Alt+D.

I had to grab another of the high-F keys (the set of which i am going to run out of eventually) to get it working:

```
set <F26>=^[d                                      
set <A-S-D>=^[D                                    
nmap <F26> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_older_paste  
nmap <A-S-D> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_newer_paste
```

Anyone know what this is all about?

Comment: Take a look at Ingo's answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16360104/1890567

Comment: What happens if you call it `<A-d>` instead of `<A-D>`?

Comment: @echristopherson It show this for `:set <A-d>`: `<ä>   ^[d`

Comment: @FDinoff The answer you linked did not provide very much in the way of answering this question but the discussion linked from that answer is quite enlightening (though sadly it has been nearly 3 years). Thanks

Comment: You may want to take a look at [vim-fixkey](https://github.com/drmikehenry/vim-fixkey).  In particular, some of Dr. Mike's [documentation](https://github.com/drmikehenry/vim-fixkey/blob/master/doc/fixkey.txt).  It could be that poor configuration is the problem (`TERM` set wrong plus Vim trying to work around it).

Answer (score 0):

Note the capital `D` in `<A-D>`; Vim treats that and `<A-S-D>` the same. Try using a small `d`:

```
set <A-d>=^[d                                      
nmap <A-d> <Plug>yankstack_substitute_older_paste
```

Comment: One might be inclined to assume this. But it is demonstrably false given my description. Did you even read what I wrote? the `<A-S-D>` binding works flawlessly, and the `<A-D>` binding fails no matter what terminal sequence I set it to, because Vim thinks it is the a-with-umlaut character. Also, this answer is completely wrong because i have never seen Vim treat the different variants differently.