# remap Enter in normal mode but not in command line

Tags: vim

I have remapped the Enter key in normal mode to add a new line:

```
nnoremap <CR> o<Esc>k
```

Works great, but now in the command line (entered by q:) this command add new line either, but I would like to leave it in default mode, this is execute the selected command from history.

So the question is, how can I remap a key in normal mode, but not in command line?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because the command buffer you open with `q:` **is** in normal mode. I hope someone will prove me wrong by answering this question. :)

Comment: This is a [common problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16360472/438329)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This autocommand does what you want:

```
augroup commandlinewindow
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
augroup END
```

It's the "command-line window", by the way, not the "command line".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to **command-line window** you'll almost certainly need this one. For **quickfix** window:

```
autocmd BufReadPost quickfix nnoremap <buffer> <CR> <CR>
```