# Vim - line break/comment remapping

Tags: vim

I've added the following line un my .vimrc to add a line break when I press enter in normal mode:

```
"" insert line break in normal mode on Enter
nmap <S-Enter> O<Esc>
nmap <CR> o<Esc>
```

This works fine except when I want to comment the current line in normal mode by pressing cmd+/ where it comments the current line and add a line break which is also commented.
How can I fix this?

Many thanks

Comment: Show the output of `:map <D-/>`, please.

Comment: <Plug>NERDCommenterToggle</Plug>

Comment: This is default behavior when adding lines after comments. It can be disabled via `set formatoptions-=o`. See `:help 'formatoptions'` and `:help fo-table`

Comment: You may want to alter you mappings to not use insert mode. I personally would use Tim Pope's unimpaired plugin but a good vanilla approach is to use `:put` with the black hole register instead. You can see some examples of these mapping in this post: [VIM - How to map Shift-Enter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter/16360472#16360472)

Answer (score 1):

The comments together give the answer; here's the summary:

You see the default formatting behavior when inserting a new line after a commented one. It's caused by the `o` value in `'formatoptions'`. You could modify your mapping to
    set formatoptions-=o

But there are alternative approaches for inserting a new empty line:

```
nnoremap <silent> <S-Enter> :put! _<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <CR> :put _<CR>
```

(PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.)

Also, there are plugins that provide this (and several related mappings):

- [unimpaired.vim - Pairs of handy bracket mappings](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1590)
- my [LineJuggler plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4140)