# vimrc mapping key doens't work as expected

Tags: vim

I wanted to map `shift+Enter` to make another line in the insert mode. Because **enter** will split the original line when the cursor is in the middle of the line. But it doesn't work like I expected. What am I missing? is there a problem to mapping **shift** key usually in .vimrc file?

```
# ~/.vimrc

" map for making a new line in the insert mode.
inoremap <S-CR> <esc>o
```

Comment: pls search before ask.  another related question (and answer) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter

Comment: Oh it is my fault that I didn't fully search it. Thank you for the links!