# Vim: Use Shift+Enter to enter new line and activate 4 backspace

Tags: vim

I use auto-indent that always begins a new line on the level of indent the last line has been.

Now how do I specify this behavior in my vimrc:

Shift + Enter enters new line (just like just enter would) but also activates the backspace key 4 times (I use spaces instead of tabs (Python)) or, to make this useful for other users too: Just one backspace (to delete the tab).

Who can set me up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter Unfortunaly Shift + Enter is not possible

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remap [shift + enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter) on the terminal version of vim.

If you're using the windows version or gvim:

```
imap <S-CR> <CR><c-d>
```

Note that you must have both shiftwidth and tabstop set to 4:

```
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

You can also simply type enter, then ctl-d.