# Can't map function keys with shift in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

I have two simple mappings to open/close and focus [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree).

```
nnoremap <F10> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <S-F10> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
```

The first mapping works, but the second one doesn't (and by that I mean that absolutely nothing happens, no errors, no glitches, etc.). Other keys in combination  with shift key work (for example, `<S-Tab>`). And as you can see from the first mapping, generic function keys work too.

Mapping shift key to other function keys and other commands doesn't work. For example this does not work:

```
nnoremap <S-F8> :pwd<CR>
```

It possible could be the system (or even hardware) issue, so I'll leave some info down here:

**PC type:** Laptop
**OS:** Arch Linux
**Architecture:** x86_64
**Kernel:** Linux 4.15.6
**Vim:** 8.0
**Keyboard:** AT Translated Set 2 keyboard

Comment: why are you binding it so far away from the homerow. i would be to lazy for such a expensive "typing move"

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359878/vim-how-to-map-shift-enter